# How to change file date attributes (at least modified date) using "dart:io"?

Tags: dart-io, dart

I want change the modificitation date and time of the file.

How I can do this in Dart platform?

Example from the .NET Framework, C# language.

```csharp
File.SetLastWriteTime(path, DateTime.Now);
```

I'm sure it's possible.

I just don't know how to do it in standard way in such a wonderful platform as the Dart.

**It is impossible in Dart**

Comment: Ah, yes. A horrible failure. I'm surprised that Dart has not added such an important feature yet. Especially as it only took Java 15 years to add it.

Comment: mezoni: Well, as you keep comparing Dart which is platform independent with .NET which is not... one needs to put things in a bit perspective.

Comment: This feature, while surely useful in corner cases, the ROI in terms of work vs value is probably quite low. I would personally be surprised if the Dart team would spend time on such a feature when there is quite a lot of other things (which have a higher ROI) to do.

Comment: @ronag I look on the Dart platform only from rational perspective.

Comment: I find it quite rational that they have not added this feature. It is probably a lot of work to get working in a platform independent way and it's value is questionable at best. Does nodejs even support this? I don't even know of any C++ framework that supports it. The only framework that supports it (that I know of) is .NET (which is not platform independent) and Java (which it took 15 years to come high enough on the priority list).

Answer (score 4):

The first method that comes to mind would be to just call `touch` using `Process`.

eg.

```
import 'dart:io';

Future touchFile(File f) {
  return Process.run("touch", [f.path]);
}

void main() {
   var f = new File('example');
   print(f.statSync().changed);
   touchFile(f).then((_) {
     print(f.statSync().changed);
   });
}
```

The equivalent code for people who are chained to windows would be

```
Future touchFile(File f) {
  return Process.run("copy", ["\b", f.path, "+,,"]);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command)

Comment: In Windows this works only if the "source" ("f.path" in our case) in the current folder. That is "copy foo+,," works but this "copy foo/baz+,," does not work. This requires more complicated handler in Windows. Thanks, for your advices but I already know about them.

Comment: So windows doesn't support a standard way of updating a file's last changed date? I don't know why you'd expect dart to do so...

Comment: But even if you have to write a more complicated handler (I wouldn't know, I haven't worked with windows in years), it's still possible in dart. You could even implement it in a platform independent way by switching on `Platform.operatingSystem`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling out to system processes seems like a serious hack. Here are two  functions that uses only Dart APIs, and is not platform dependent. One is synchronous, and the other asynchronous. Use whichever version suits your needs.

```
void touchFileSync(File file) {
  final touchfile = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.append);
  touchfile.flushSync();
  touchfile.closeSync();
}

Future<void> touchFile(File file) async {
  final touchfile = await file.open(mode: FileMode.append);
  await touchfile.flush();
  await touchfile.close();
}
```

This will update the last modified time.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 9, 2017, you can set a file modified date like this:

```
var myFile = await File('foo.bar').openWrite();
await myFile.setLastModified(DateTime.now());
```